# how to hide button when textbox value isn't null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having trouble finding any documentation on how to hide a button when the field it populates has a value. All the reference articles i've found are referring to hiding a button if the value IS null.

I need "rmabutton" to be disabled or hidden if "helpdesk_ticket_custom_field_rma_210279" is already populated with a value

```
<input type="button" id="rmabutton" onclick="RMA()" value="Generate RMA #">
<script type="text/javascript">

function RMA(){
//formatted day
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var day = (d < 10) ? '0' + d : d;

//formatted month
    var m = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var month = (m < 10) ? '0' + m : m;

//formatted year
    var yy = date.getYear();
    var year = (yy < 1000) ? yy + 1900 : yy;

//grab agent ID
    var agent = $("helpdesk_ticket_responder_id").value;

//Isolate agent ID last 5 digits for use in RMA as agent number 
    var agent_short = agent.slice(5,10)

//grab ticket number and eliminate special characters
    var ticket = $("ticket-display-id").innerHTML.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "");

//parse new RMA # day-month-year-agent-ticket
    var rma_number = ""+month+""+day+""+year+"-"+agent_short+"-"+ticket+"";

//replace RMA field contents with new RMA # 
  $("helpdesk_ticket_custom_field_rma_210279").value = rma_number;  
 } 
</script>
```

Comment: another note, the box needs to show/hide depending on whether or not that field has a value.

If the box is null - Show button
if the box has a value - hide button

Comment: what is helpdesk_ticket...? I don't see it in the html

Comment: If you found explanations of how to hide the button when the value is empty, just reverse the test and it will hide when it has a value.

Comment: The helpdesk_ticket elements are from the platform this javascript is being plugged into. So far this code is working flawlessly, I just need a suggestion on how to hide my button depending on the conditions i provided.

Comment: how is this working? $("helpdesk_ticket_custom_field_rma_210279").value = rma_number; ?

Comment: @Barmar oddly enough, I tried it and couldn't get it to work. 

if(!$('input').val()){
    $('#button').hide();
}
else {
    $('#button').show();
}

Comment: @Sushil 

 $("helpdesk_ticket_custom_field_rma_210279").value = rma_number;
Queries the ID and checks the value. By default it's empty, When the function is performed after onclick() it populates the ID with the new RMA number provided by 
var rma_number = ""+month+""+day+""+year+"-"+agent_short+"-"+ticket+"";

Comment: are you looking for something like this?? http://jsfiddle.net/L0ahh13f/

Comment: here's the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/L0ahh13f/1/

Answer (score 1):

Use a `keyup` handler on the RMA input field that tests the value, and toggle the visibility of the button depending on it.

```js
$("#helpdesk_ticket_custom_field_rma_210279").keyup(function() {
  $("#rmabutton").toggle(this.value == '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="helpdesk_ticket_custom_field_rma_210279">
<input type="button" id="rmabutton" value="Generate RMA #">
```

Answer (score 0):

hi check this out  http://jsfiddle.net/elviz/2z1nvg7y/

```
    $("#helpdesk_ticket_custom_field_rma_210279").keyup(function(){

      $("#rmabutton").hide();

    });
```